# Algorithm to detect if a file name list has matching image file name?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a lot of files. Some are archives that are either `zip` or `rar` files. Some of them have images with matching name.
For example:

```
d:\\data\\archive1.zip
d:\\data\\archive1.jpg
d:\\data\\archive2.rar
d:\\data\\archive2.png
d:\\data\\archive3.zip [This one doesn't have an image]
```

Image extensions are `png`, `jpg`, `jpeg`, `webp`, `gif`, etc.

I need a way to differentiate those files that has an image pair of same name and those that doesn't have such pair.
These file paths are in a list of strings. I tried doing the following getting only path without the extension:

```
for i in range(len(file_path_list)):
    print(file_path_list[i])
    fname = file_path_list[i].rsplit('.',1)[0]
    tosearch_list = list(file_path_list)
    tosearch_list.pop(i)

    for x in tosearch_list:
        if x.rsplit('.',1)[0] == fname:
            print(f"{x} is a matching file")
```

Then for each entry in the list I would have to search the remaining entry in the list without extension to find the matches.

`archive1` would have to search through remaining entries in the list and find the other files with same name. The names are not in any particular order. Is this the fastest way or are there any better ways?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: Consider making a `set` of the stems of the archives and a second `set` of the stems of the images. You can then easily find the intersection and difference with `set` operations.

Comment: That's a good idea @MarkSetchell

Comment: 1) Create a dictionary `{ 'd:\\data\\archive1'=>['zip', 'jpg'], 'd:\\data\\archive2'=>['rar', 'png'], 'd:\\data\\archive3'=>['zip'] }`. 2) Remove each file suffix from values that does not denote an image file: `{ 'd:\\data\\archive1'=>['jpg'], 'd:\\data\\archive2'=>['rar', 'png'], 'd:\\data\\archive3'=>[] }`. 3) Remove each key-value pair whose value contains fewer than two elements: `{ 'd:\\data\\archive2'=>['rar', 'png'] }`. The steps could of course be combined.

Comment: Here is the suggestion in my previous comment implemented in Ruby. I mention this in case a reader familiar with both languages wishes to add an answer using this approach. Below `files` equals an array of the five filenames given in the example and `image_suffixes = ['jpg', 'rar', 'png']`. Then `files.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|; prefix, suffix = s.split(/\.(?=[^.]+$)/); next unless image_suffixes.include?(suffix); h[prefix] = [] unless h.key?(prefix); h[prefix] << suffix; end.select { |_,v| v.size > 1 } #=> {"d:\\data\\archive2"=>["rar", "png"]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dict for zip files and image files, and get the missing names via set operation.  Here is an example:

```
file_path_list=[
    "d:\\data\\archive1.zip",
    "d:\\data\\archive1.jpg",
    "d:\\data\\archive2.rar",
    "d:\\data\\archive2.png",
    "d:\\data\\archive3.zip",
    "d:\\data\\some.bad.filename.zip",
]

zip_dict = {}
img_dict = {}
for path in file_path_list:
    fname, fext = os.path.splitext(path)
    if fext in (".zip", ".rar"):
        zip_dict[fname] = path
    elif fext in (".jpg", ".png"):
        img_dict[fname] = path

zip_no_img_names = set(zip_dict.keys()).difference(set(img_dict.keys()))

soln_files = [zip_dict[k] for k in zip_no_img_names] 
# ['d:\\data\\archive3.zip', 'd:\\data\\some.bad.filename.zip']
```

Comment: This will not work if file name has other . in them for example blabla.blabla.jpg etc. But I get the idea. Will it be faster?

Comment: ok, you got me :) that was a quick and dirty solution.  It's better to parse the filenames with something like `os.path.splitext` as I've edited it to.  I was being lazy with the details

Comment: I think this solution is a good balance between performant, readable, and easy to edit (a personal definition of good code).  Performance should be linear in the number of files thanks to using dict and sets as @Mark Setchell suggested

Comment: Note: you can just write `zip_no_img_names = set(zip_dict.keys()).difference(img_dict.keys())` without the second explicit call to `set`. Or alternatively `zip_no_img_names = set(zip_dict.keys()) - set(img_dict.keys())`. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.copy) says that `zip_no_img_names = set(zip_dict.keys()) - img_dict.keys()` should not work, but it does on my machine.

Comment: The documentation: *"Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`."*

Comment: @Stef another case of being lazy.  Rather, I've been burned by the difference in behavior before, so now I just cast as `set` for clarity.  I might also not need `.keys()`, but it makes it super explicit what the set elements are.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cut off an extension part (i.e. `.png`), the simplest way is to move backward from the end towards the beginning until you see the first `.` char.
2. Once cut, keep either `dict` or `set` where the key is the remaining `string` - a file name without extension to track repetitions efficiently.
3. If such repetition is found, then you got a match. In case you care about extensions and matches that could come in different combinations, you might want to use `dict` where the key is `string` and the value of type `list` of found extensions. For example if you had both `my_file.png` and `my_file.txt`, `my_dict['my_file'] == {'.png', '.txt'}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it by using the [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function in conjunction with [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) instances to hold the file paths (to make them easier to deal with).

The code first convert the filepath to `Path`s, and then groups them by sorting them and ignoring the file extensions. Next it uses the `groupby()` function group the sorted list into sub-lists of files sharing a common path. Once that's done, it prints out each groups and an indicator of whether one of them is an image file.

```
from itertools import groupby
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint


image_extensions = {'.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.webp', '.gif'}
archive_extensions = {'.zip', '.rar'}
allowed_extensions = image_extensions | archive_extensions

# Raw filepaths in random order.
filepaths = ['d:\\data\\archive1.zip',
             'd:\\data\\archive3.zip',
             'd:\\data\\archive2.rar',
             'd:\\data\\archive2.png',
             'd:\\data\\archive1.jpg']

filepaths = [Path(filepath) for filepath in filepaths]  # Convert to pathlib.Paths
filepaths = [filepath for filepath in filepaths if filepath.suffix in allowed_extensions]

def sort_key(filepath):
    return ''.join(filepath.parts[:-1]), filepath.parts[-1]

filepaths.sort(key=sort_key)
#pprint(filepaths)

def keyfunc(filepath):
    return ''.join(filepath.parts[:-1]), filepath.stem

groups = []
for k, g in groupby(filepaths, keyfunc):
    groups.append(list(g))  # Append filepath group.

for group in groups:
    has_image = any((filepath.suffix in image_extensions) for filepath in group)
    print(group, 'Has image' if has_image else 'No image')
```

Sample output:

```
[WindowsPath('d:/data/archive1.jpg'), WindowsPath('d:/data/archive1.zip')] Has image
[WindowsPath('d:/data/archive2.png'), WindowsPath('d:/data/archive2.rar')] Has image
[WindowsPath('d:/data/archive3.zip')] No image
```